# How to Replace some binaries occurrence between two sequence regardless the content with PERL?

Tags: regex, perl, binaries

i want to replace some occurrence in a bin file. for exemple

file.bin content :

```
0A0A0A0A954654370B0B0B0B
0A0A0A0A453426540B0B0B0B
```

I want to modify the content between 0A0A0A0A and 0B0B0B0B without care of the original content and replacing with
0A0A0A0A12345678B0B0B0B in each line

i  use perl regex command : `perl -pi -e 's|\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\x95\x46\x54\x37\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B|\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\x12\x34\x56\x78\xB0\xB0\xB\x0B|g' /file.bin`

but how to tell perl to ignore the content between 0A and 0B in source section to use one command for the all content of file ?

Comment: I've never done regex on binary content but I would try to replace `\x95\x46\x54\x37` by `.{4}` meaning any char 4 times. If it doesn't work due to the length, you could also try `.+?` which means any char 1 or N times but in an ungreedy way, so that it doesn't "eat" to many chars and stops when it finds `\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that you used `\xB0\xB0\xB\x0B` instead of `\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B`.

---

Next, we have to cover a problem with the approach being taken.

Since you say it's a binary file, and since you're using `\x0A`, I'm assuming `0A` represents the single byte with that hex value.

If so, `0A` is presumed to be a line feed by Perl. The substitution is applied to each of these in turn:

```
0A
0A
0A
0A
954654370B0B0B0B0A
0A
0A
0A
453426540B0B0B0B
```

Your pattern never matches, so no substitution occurs.

This could be resolved by reading the entire file at once using `-0777`.

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's{\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\x95\x46\x54\x37\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B}
                 {\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\x12\x34\x56\x78\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B}g'
```

---

Finally, on to the question you asked.

`.` matches any character other than `0A`. But `.` with `/s` matches any character, period. So you could use `....` (with `/s`), or `.{4}` (with `/s`).

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's{\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A.{4}\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B}
                 {\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\x12\x34\x56\x78\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B}sg'
```

or

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's/\x0A\x0A\x0A\x0A\K.{4}(?=\x0B\x0B\x0B\x0B)/\x12\x34\x56\x78/sg'
```